# JAVA display in sets of 13

Tags: java, set

I am sure this is a pretty easy question, but I am pretty rusty on my programming.  I need to write code that will show all numbers between 14859 - 26551 in sets of 13.

So far I just have the normal for loop to show all the numbers, no sure how to get sets of 13.

```
for(i=14859; i < 26551; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: "Sets of 13" as in "groups of thirteen consecutive numbers", delimited by e.g. an empty line?

Comment: I thought of that, but when I change i++ to i+13 it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to display your numbers as Jukka said in comments:

```
for(i=14859; i < 26551; i++){
    if((i-14858)%13==0)
        System.out.println(); // or anything delimiting your sets
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or if you want to display only one number every 13:

```
for(i=14859; i < 26551; i+=13){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

You can't just type `i+13` as you said you tried in comments: 3rd argument in a for loop is an assignment, so you have to assign something to a variable.

Comment: thanks a million x.l. ant.  Cant believe i let my java skills get this out of hand lol

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=14859; i < 26551; i++)
    System.out.print(((i % 13 != 0) ? ", " + i : "\n"));
```